# Throtling in both sagemakerruntime and sagemakerfeaturestoreruntime

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker, feature-store

We have not set the **rate limit** values in both `feature-store` and `sagemaker` aws service but we are getting `rate limit exceeded` errors in very low RPS.

**Case** :-

`Sagemaker` : Current RPS to SageMaker service is `5 RPS`. It goes to `12 RPS` in fractions of millis at 8pm due to sale, which is not very high, but it's a sudden jump. At this point in time `SageMaker` calls give us error as below :

```
Message : Rate exceeded (Service: SageMakerRuntime, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 64a3ba3d-fc15-406b-b73a-ebc321e28ff8)
```

`FeatureStore` : Current RPS to FeatureStore service is `55 RPS`. It goes to `100RPS` in fractions of millis at 8pm due to sale, which is not something that feature-store can't handle. At this point in time `FeatureStore` calls gives us error as below:

```
Message : Rate exceeded (Service: SageMakerFeatureStoreRuntime, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 5b7341bd-21e1-4ec9-a2d6-c204244e9780).
```

Some other errors the has been observed while calling the `feature-store` service, though the quantum of these errors are very less like 3 times a day or so but they are there. Given below 2 errors.

```
Error: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection reset at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException

Error: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111).
```

> Should we not worry about these 2 errors ?

This is how we configured the `Feature-store` and `SageMaker` client in our application.

Java version: 17
aws sdk version : 2.20.26

**FeatureStore client config**:

```
    ClientOverrideConfiguration clientOverrideConfiguration = ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
            .apiCallTimeout(Duration.of(featureStoreConfig.getApiCallAttemptTimeout(), ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
            .retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.builder().numRetries(0).build())
            .build();

    featureStoreRuntimeClient = SageMakerFeatureStoreRuntimeClient.builder()
            .overrideConfiguration(clientOverrideConfiguration)
            .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
            .region(Region.AP_SOUTHEAST_1).build();
```

**Sagemaker client config** :

```
    ClientOverrideConfiguration clientOverrideConfiguration = ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
            .apiCallTimeout(Duration.of(sageMakerConfig.getApiCallAttemptTimeout(), ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
            .retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.builder().numRetries(0).build())
    .build();

    sageMakerRuntimeClient = SageMakerRuntimeClient.builder()
            .overrideConfiguration(clientOverrideConfiguration)
            .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create())
            .region(Region.AP_SOUTHEAST_1)
            .build();
```

> Another interesting observation is if we keep the RPS same as peak RPS
> for some amount of time. This rate limit exceeded error goes away. It
> seems this **throttling** only happens on sudden increase of RPS. How
> do we solve for this? Could 0 retry be the issue here, but why at the calls are being throttled at first place with such low `RPS` ?